# Dynamic equal height columns with text and a full height <img>

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a layout that requires two equal height columns. The left column contains an img (of unknown size), and the right column will contain text. I want the img to fill its container, and want to refrain from using flexbox (have to support older browsers) or js (if possible).

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="cell">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/500" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="cell">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus dolorem deserunt vero atque fugit autem necessitatibus iure numquam veritatis nostrum!</div>
</div>
```

I've been able to make this work by setting the img as a background, but I'm wondering if someone knows a way to make this work with an img in the html. So far, this is what I have (scss):

```
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
  &:first-of-type {
    background: green;
  }
}
```

This would work for two columns of text, but it doesn't when you include an img. Is there still a way to make this work with plain css?

Working example (with only text): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vmtEg/

Working (when the img isn't as wide as the column containing it): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgIzC/

Not working (with an img smaller than the container): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wmIri/ (almost there though, I feel like all I need is a container that will pull the image to full height, and then cut off the x overflow. Don't know how to get there though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you don't want to set a height to your table, the only CSS solution would be to add (so your image resizes in it's container) :

```
.cell img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/62k7n/3/)**

FULL CSS :

```
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 50%;
    background: blue;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width: 50%;
    background: red;
}
.cell img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    display:block;

}
.cell:first-of-type {
    background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you want the column height fixed, but you can see below piece of code:

```
<table>
```

http://placekitten44.com/500/500

```
<td width="50%">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus dolorem deserunt vero atque fugit autem necessitatibus iure numquam veritatis nostrum!</td>
```

Comment: Html tables for layout though.. Also I can't fix the column height since the content is dynamic.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing using html table?

Comment: Well it isn't tabular data that I'm formatting. So tables wouldn't be appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

The image that you specify in `<img src=''>` is not a background image but a foreground image content of the `img` element, thus will not react to CSS background styling.

You can set the background image in CSS as normal like [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/pKfkd/)

```
.image {
  background:url("http://placekitten.com/500/500")no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
 }
```

or you need javascript/jquery for that

Comment: Yeah I know, I wasn't really clear with that, sorry. What I meant was is that I can get it to work when I set it as a css background image, but not when I place the image in html (as in my example code). But I want it to be a foreground image since it is important content.

Answer (score 0):

Try in jquery. Just add **col** class to the div's you want the same resize

```
var maxheight = 0;
$("div.col").each(function(){
  if($(this).height() > maxheight) { maxheight = $(this).height(); }
});

$("div.col").height(maxheight);
```

Tell me something!

Comment: Yeah, but I'm trying to do this without .js because it's styling and not behaviour. So I'd rather do this without js (see question).